# Cloud Firestore 10000 writes/second Limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This question might be silly :)

According to Firestore documentation, the maximum number of writes allowed per second against a database is 10k.  Let's say if I am batching my writes and committing it for every 500 records,

Does  one commit will be considered as a single write or 500 writes ?

Comment: Did you find a way to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The limitation comes from the fact that Firestore has to update indexes, which are shared between the documents in a collection, and in the case of collection groups, even between collections. There is a limit on how many writes it can perform to an index (that is shared between multiple data centers), and each document that is written requires an update to the index(es) too.

So in your example the single batch commit with 500 documents results in 500 index updates, and thus counts as 500 writes. Keep in mind though that this is not a hard-coded limit, but a soft limit.

Comment: Ohh, may be then we need to update the google documentation I guess, in the doc, it is mentioned under the hard limit section.

Comment: What can happen if we exceed this limit ? Can the reads be slow ? I am trying to do a bulk import of data from BigQuery to Firestore using Dataflow (as a daily job) and if this can slow down the reads I might have to consider restricting the write parallelizm.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I misremember, as I tend to trust the docs on things like this. Read performance is not affected by write limits afaik.

Comment: so conclusion - even if i try to write more than 10k at a time, firestore will not allow me to do it and hence as a developer I dont have to worry about limiting the writes ? Also hitting the 10k write limit will not slow down my reads  ?